# Guzzle\Post works, but with createRequest I get null

Tags: php, request, guzzle

so this works:

```
$request = $this->client->post($this->getRequestPath(), [
    "body" => [
        "grant_type"        => "client_credentials",
        "client_id"         =>  $this->config['client_id'],
        "client_secret" =>  $this->config['client_secret'],
        "scope"                 =>  $this->config['scope'],
    ],
    "debug" => true
]);
```

However this does NOT work

```
$request = $client->createRequest($type, $this->getRequestPath(), ['body' => $parameters, "debug" => true] );
$client->send($request);
```

I would like to work with `createRequest`because as you can see, I want to be flexible on the type of request I send.

Any ideas why it is not working? I do get a debug report and it seems fine, I also get `null` as a return value, and I think the body is transferred differently to the `post` method which is why my api does not pick it up correctly.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it does work like this, only thing is, that get requests require "query" instead of "body".